# Problem with Android Studio - Virtual Manager doesn't respond

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-launcher, virtual-device-manager

I have a problem with Virtual Device Manager in Android Studio app. Well, after creating the virtual device and turning it on, the display and the device itself doesn't respond. The black screen remains for a long time until the loading time is exceeded. Even the cold boot option does nothing. Has anyone encountered such a problem? I would be grateful for quick help, best regards.

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on Android...
› Opening emulator Pixel_Tablet_API_34
Error: It took too long to start the Android emulator: Pixel_Tablet_API_34. You can try starting the emulator manually from the terminal with: C:\Users{myUserName}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_Tablet_API_34
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50km0.png)one

I tried with different versions of the application, downloading the appropriate SDK and starting the device via cold boot

Comment: Please edit your post to include the type of PC (Windows, Mac, Linux), CPU, RAM, and GPU if available. Be aware of the minimum PC requirements to run the Emulator: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements . If was working prior, and you updated the Android SDK/tools, try deleting and recreating the emulator.